# Mapping nested arrays using map in es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to loop through nested arrays using map.

```
const results = [
{
    id: 1,
    details: [
        {
            color: "red",
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    details: [
        {
            color: "blue",
        }
    ]
}]

const list1 = results.map(car => { 
   return car.details;
})

const list2 = list.map(details => {
   return {
     detail: details.color
} 
});

console.log(list1);
console.log(list2);
```

List1 is displaying fine:

```
​​​​​[ [ { color: 'red' } ], [ { color: 'blue' } ] ]​​​​​
```

However with list2 I am getting the following:

```
[ { detail: undefined }, { detail: undefined } ]​​​​​
```

Could anyone help me to map through the nested array?

Comment: What you expect this to be `[ { detail: undefined }, { detail: undefined } ]​​​​​` ?

Comment: you are using list.map, it should be list1.map(..., for list2

Comment: What is `list` ?

Comment: use should use `list1` instead of `list` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```js
const results = [
{
    id: 1,
    details: [
        {
            color: "red",
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    details: [
        {
            color: "blue",
        }
    ]
}]

const list1 = results.map(car => { 
   return car.details;
});

// assuming there was a typo here it should be list1
const list2 = list1.map(details => { 
   return {
     detail: details[0].color // details is an array
   } 
});

console.log(list1);
console.log(list2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to map the inner array values and concat them to a single array.

```js
var results = [{ id: 1, details: [{ color: "red" }] }, { id: 2, details: [{ color: "blue" }] }],
    list1 = results.map(({ details }) =>  details);
    list2 = list1.reduce(
        (r, details) => r.concat(details.map(({ color: detail }) => ({ detail }))),
        []
    );

console.log(list2);
console.log(list1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect variable name `list` that will be `list1` and then inside the `map` you need to access the object of each `details` array for `list1`:

```js
const results = [
{
    id: 1,
    details: [
        {
            color: "red",
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    details: [
        {
            color: "blue",
        }
    ]
}]

const list1 = results.map(car => { 
   return car.details;
})

const list2 = list1.map(details => {
   return {
     detail: details[0].color
} 
});

console.log(list1);
console.log(list2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `color` `properties` of each of the `details` within `list2` are nested within `arrays`.

To expose them: said `arrays` must be `flattened`.

`Arrays` of `arrays` can be `flattened` tersely using [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like so:

```
const flattened = [].concat.apply([], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input
const input = [{id: 1, details: [{color: "red"}]},{id: 2,details: [{color: "blue"}]}]

// Details.
const details = input.map(car => car.details)

// Colors.
const colors = [].concat.apply([], details).map(({color}) => ({detail: color}));

// Proof.
console.log('Details', details)
console.log('Colors', colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems with your code are:

1. Typo in `list`. You wanted to use `list1` instead.
2. In `list1`, `details` is an array. So you need to get the color on the basis of index.

```js
const results = [{
    id: 1,
    details: [{
      color: "red",
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    details: [{
      color: "blue",
    }]
  }
]

const list1 = results.map(car => car.details);
const list2 = list1.map(details => ({ detail: details[0].color }));
console.log(list1);
console.log(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You forgot the dynamic index of the array.    
const results = [
      {
          id: 1,
          details: [
              {
                    color: "red",
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          details: [
          {
              color: "blue",
              }
          ]
      }]

      const list1 = results.map((car, i) => { 
        return car[i].details;
      })

      const list2 = list.map((details, i) => {
        return {
          detail: details[i].color
      } 
      });

      console.log(list1);
      console.log(list2);
```